# How to remove an errant ZFS spare entry?

Tags: raid, zfs, nas

I have a ZFS spare reporting in an odd way.  There is no `sda` spare.  The spare "was" actually in use, listed as `spare3` in screenshot below.  However,  `sda` is in fact the non-ZFS boot drive.

Do I just need to zfs replace it?

```
$ zpool status
  pool: san
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: resilvered 1.23T in 0 days 11:23:38 with 0 errors on Sun Nov 15 08:42:36 2020
config:

        NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        san                                             ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD20EZRX-00DC0B0_WD-WMC1T3458346    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD2000FYYZ-01UL1B1_WD-WCC1P1171516  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD20EZRX-19D8PB0_WD-WCC4M0428332    ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-35000cca01cdc15d0                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD20EARX-00PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ490344    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD2000FYYZ-01UL1B1_WD-WCC1P0891973  ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          sda                                           FAULTED   corrupted data
```

```
$ lsscsi
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD5000AACS-0 1B01  /dev/sda
[4:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GH22NS30 1.01  /dev/sr0
[5:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD2000FYYZ-0 1K02  /dev/sdb
[6:0:0:0]    disk    HITACHI  HUS72302CLAR2000 C442  /dev/sdc
[6:0:1:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD20EZRX-00D 0A80  /dev/sdd
[6:0:2:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD20EZRX-19D 0A81  /dev/sde
[6:0:3:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD2000FYYZ-0 1K02  /dev/sdf
[6:0:4:0]    disk    HITACHI  HUS72302CLAR2000 C442  /dev/sdg
[6:0:5:0]    disk    ATA      ST2000NM0011     PA09  /dev/sdh
[6:0:6:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD2000FYYZ-0 1K02  /dev/sdi
[6:0:7:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD20EARX-00P AB51  /dev/sdj
```

I want to remove the `sda` spare entry completely if possible.  Its not tied to any spare. Is it possible to remove the errant spare entry?

Some background info. I have had only one spare.  This spare automatically took over as an active drive, some time last year, to fill in as a spare for a failing drive on a raidZ2 setup.  ZFS had then reported the failed drive as corrupted, and the spare as active, something along those line.

Later down the road, some months ago, the spare crashed out, from bad sectors (was just a test device with bad sectors that had recently been re-zeroed)

I went on using the pool, and finally yesterday, it got connected up with some new replacement drives, to get things back in order.

I believe it's fair to say that the screenshot I took yesterday is a fair representation of what the failed spare condition looked like. I'm not clear, but I'm thinking its only 1 spare drive, that is being incorrectly reported, but i will check if i can figure out how.

[image: zfs failed spare output raidz2]

So the screenshot directly above is the "before" status. The code snip on top shows the "current" status, which was taken after a resilver of the spare replacement, which was a ZFS replace of `Z1P07NVZ` with `scsi-35000cca01cdc15d0`.

So what can i do about /dev/sda showing up in the zfs list? What's the pool's problem with sda?  I only remember ever connecting, and enrolling 1 spare.

I realize its possible the old corrupt spare may be sitting in the array, and that which is reporting as the corrupted one.  How do i figure out if it is, short of opening the case?

I can try to replace the spare entry with a real spare, so long the one that says corrupted gets gone; however, WHAT I'M WORRIED ABOUT is if I `zfs replace /dev/sda with/something/else` then `sda` is my boot volume, so we don't want any writing to happen to the actual `/dev/sda`.

Hence, we have the conundrum.

I think I have 2, maybe 3 drives I can add in.  I want to first get the spare entry either GONE, or updated to a working drive, to the end effect i only have ONE spare entry, or none, but not two.  After this i want to try adding in another volume to increase the span size by 1.  I think this post concerns mostly the former, the spare problem.  If anybody has any input on the latter though (increasing the span size), if it may play a role in getting this resolved, then that may work as well.